# Return http busy code from google cluster managed by kubernetes

Tags: load-balancing, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I've simple following configuration of the cluster: 3 nodes on 3 machines. On top of each node i have 1 pod. Each pod has readinessProbe. All these pods exposed to one service object with type NodePort. On the top of this object i have the following ingress object:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dess-ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: dess-index
    servicePort: 2280
```

This configuration works fine, but i want to return http busy status when all readinessProbe fails and cluster cannot handle more requests. How can I do that? And a related question - google compute engine allows to specify backend service capacity based on cpu utilisation or requests per second for load-balancing purposes. Can I do the following with the kubernetes service object?

Comment: What kind of ingress are you using? K8s Services are "stupid", i.e. only iptables rules. The ingress you are using has to generate an HTTP response if your pods can't.

Comment: For your second question, have you looked at [HPA](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/horizontal-pod-autoscaling/) ?

Comment: @tex, i'm using basic kubernetes ingress configuration, like i mentioned in the original post. And how can I specify that ingress should generate in this case an HTTP response?

Comment: @AnirudhRamanathan, thanks, that was I looking for the second question!